Encoding problem while querying data from TeradataDB to dataframe in Python
I have this problem that I can't solve. We have table in Teradata database. Let's say that our table has only one row (Świdnica - Polish word) and one column (addresses).
Column 'addresses' is defined as:
addresses VARCHAR(80) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC

Let's say that we query the data:
select addresses from WH_table

and in Teradata Studio we get nice result:
ŚWIDNICA

but when I try to query using extension to SQLAlchemy named teradatasqlalchemy I get:
'\x8cWIDNICA'

My code looks like this:
import sqlalchemy as sqlal
import pandas as pd

engine = sqlal.create_engine('teradatasql://ip_to_my_db/?user=user&password=pass!&tmode=TERA', pool_size=5)
conn = engine.connect()

try:
    query = """select addresses from WH_table"""
    data = pd.read_sql(query, con = conn)
    print(data)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

As far as I know teradatasqlalchemy query returns data as UTF-8. I tried encoding and decoding data using UTF8, Latin1, cp1252 and iso-8859-1, but I still can't get it to just return 'ŚWIDNICA'. I could replace \x8c to Ś, but probably as you would expect. It will work for a couple of examples and not for whole table which has more then thousand rows.

That looks like cp1250.

This is technically not a "problem while querying" it's a problem with the table definition and loading. The LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH ACUTE (U+015A) is not within the Teradata LATIN repertoire. To store this value properly, the column should be defined as CHARACTER SET UNICODE and loading should be done using UTF8 or UTF16 session character set (with appropriate translation from client character set depending on the source). Apparently this is CP1250 data loaded with ASCII session character set (implying the data is all Teradata LATIN - but it isn't).

While it may be possible to craft a workaround, you would be better off correcting the design and loading process. You may be able to unload the existing data with some other tool using session character set ASCII and then reload it correctly as Unicode.

@Fred This is exactly what I was afraid of because I have no insight into the process of loading this table and I thought that it might be a problem with incorrectly loaded data. It will be a long week then. If I find a workaround I'll post it as a solution.

@Fred  - How can this even get loaded into a LATIN table?  Wouldn't  you just get an error about an untranslatable character?

@Andrew - When you use session character set "ASCII", legacy behavior is to simply assume the data is Teradata LATIN on the client and store / retrieve bytes as-is with no translation (rather than restricting you to actual 7-bit ASCII). While that approach has been deprecated for a long time it is still an option for some client/driver/database configurations.

Perhaps use CHAR2HEXINT function in the query to retrieve the data as a hex string (twice as long), then convert that to a bytes object and then decode the bytes as cp1250?

Using the answers from comment under the original question I figured out a way to make it work. It's not the most optimized answer, but works for small dataframes.
import sqlalchemy as sqlal
import pandas as pd

engine = sqlal.create_engine('teradatasql://ip_to_my_db/?user=user&password=pass!&tmode=TERA', pool_size=5)
conn = engine.connect()

try:
    query = """select addresses from WH_table"""
    data = pd.read_sql(query, con = conn) # read data from db using query
    for column, series in data.items():
        for item in series:
            # change string to hex
            str_to_hex = ''.join(hex(ord(x))[2:] for x in item) 
            # change hex to bytes and decode using encoding of your choice
            hex_to_word = bytes.fromhex(str_to_hex).decode('cp1250')
            # replace the word in df
            series.replace(item, hex_to_word, inplace = True)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

It works well for small df, but going through each item in df is not very efficient as you can imagine.
